# C# equivalent of Java Class<? extends Base>?

Tags: c#

I'd like to be able to write a method in C# similar to how I would in Java... To pass in a Class object that is a subclass of some super class... but the best I can find for C# is the following:

```
public void someMethod(Type t) {
  if (t == typeof(SomeType)) ...
}
```

Is there any way I can enforce in the method signature that the parameter has to be either the type SomeType or one of its inheritors?

I'm not looking to pass in an instance of said Type. I want to pass the Type itself in as a parameter.

### Edit

Here's a bit of context.

I want to make an EventManager class that contains a `Dictionary<SomeEventType, ICollection<EventHandler>>` object, and a method `registerEventHandler(Type t, EventHandler eh)` that maps a given `Type` to an `EventHandler`.

In Java, I would accomplish it as such:

```
private static Map<Class<? extends Event>, Collection<EventHandler>> eventHandlers;

public static void registerListener(Class<? extends Event> event, EventHandler handler) {
  if (eventHandlers.get(event) == null) {
    HashMap<EventHandler> handlers = new HashMap<EventHandler>()
    eventHandlers.put(event, handlers) ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you do `public void someMethod(Base b)`, and then pass in a `Base` or anything that extends `Base`? I assume this isn't what you mean to ask, but I'm having trouble deciphering your question.

Comment: Why don't you simply write `public void someMethod(SomeType t)`?

Comment: My question is that, where in Java I could have a method `public void someMethod(Class<? extends Base> clazz)` and then I could pass in `Base.class` or `ClassThatExtendsBase.class` as a parameter. I'm looking for the same behavior in C#.

Comment: Ah, you want to pass in a type, not an instance of a type, and you want that type to be one that extends a specific type?

Comment: @EricFinn yes, that is correct

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use a generic constraint.

```
public void someMethod<T>() where T : SomeType {
    Type myType = typeof(T);

    // do something with myType
}
```

Here's an implementation of your desired use case.

```
class EventManager {
    public Dictionary<Type, ICollection<EventHandler>> 
        HandlerMap = new Dictionary<Type, ICollection<EventHandler>>();

    public void RegisterEventHandler<TEvent>(EventHandler eh) 
        where TEvent: SomeEventType 
    {
        Type eventType = typeof(TEvent);

        if (!HandlerMap.ContainsKey(eventType)) {
            HandlerMap[eventType] = new List<EventHandler>();
        }

        HandlerMap[eventType].Add(eh);
    }
}
```

You would call it like this.

```
var em = new EventManager();
EventHandler eh = null; // or whatever
em.RegisterEventHandler<SpecificEventType>(eh);
```

Comment: How do you call that method? I'm not as familiar with C# as I am with Java, sadly.

Answer (score 1):

i don't really know java but you mean something like this?

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class bar
    { public void stuff() { } }

    class foo : bar
    { }

    class doublefoo : bar
    { }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            someMethod<foo>();
            someMethod<doublefoo>();
        }

        public static void someMethod<t>() where t: bar, new()
        {
            t myBar = new t();

            myBar.stuff();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding, that won't do what I'm looking for. I don't want to pass in an instance of an object as a parameter. I want to pass in its Type. Each class has exactly one Type.

Answer (score 1):

You can have the behavior through defining a generic type.

```
public void SomeMethod<T>(T obj) where T : AbstractClass
{
}
```

But nothing also prevents you from just using the base class as the parameter

```
public void SomeMethod(AbstractClass obj)
{
}
```

Comment: Abstract class, or just base class? The OP didn't say anything about abstract.

Comment: I like the approach, but you don't need the `T obj` parameter.  The question is asking to pass the type.  To get that, you'd use `typeof(T)`.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, you can do this with a generic type parameter... but if you only have the value as a `Type` and want to pass it in as a regular argument (e.g. because it's been passed to your method that way), there's no way of doing it. `Type` isn't generic in .NET, so there's no concept of constraining the parameter to be the `Type` representing a particular class or its subclasses, just as there's no concept of constraining a string parameter to be of a certain length or longer.

If you *do* know the types at compile-time when calling the method, then using a generic type parameter as per [recursive's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26685487/22656) is absolutely the way to go.

Comment: @agent154: Please add the context into your *question* - not comments.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the first case where you say it's not possible with an example? I'm not sure I follow. How could recursive's answer break under that case?

Comment: @agent154: Well recursive's answer *does* use a generic type parameter. My point is that if you *don't* want a generic method - if you just want a method accepting a parameter of type `Type` - then there's no way of constraining what the value of that parameter will be.